# Why is this while loop getting stuck?

Tags: c#, while-loop, do-while

I just wrote a simple c# code for calculating the factorial of a number but the the program is getting stuck on the last name. Could someone why it's getting stuck?

Thanks,

Omin

```
using System;

//1. Write a program which finds the factorial of a number entered by the user.

namespace Beginner1{

class ProblemOne
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        bool play = true;
        while ( play ) {
            Console.Write ("Type in the number you would like to find Factorial of: ");
            int num = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine ());
            int sum = 1;
            for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
                sum = sum * i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("The Factorial of {0} is {1}", num, sum);
            Console.Write ( "Would you like to play again? (Y or N): " );
            string ans = Console.ReadLine();
            do {
                if( ans == "Y" || ans == "y" )  {
                    play = true;
                    //break;
                }
                else if( ans == "N" || ans == "n" ) {
                    play = false;
                    //break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write( "You have entered an invalid answer. Please choose from either Y or N: ");
                    ans = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            } while ( (ans != "Y") || (ans != "y") || (ans != "N") || (ans != "n") );
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: This does not find the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of anything...

Comment: Stepping through code with the debugger is your friend!

Answer (score 8):

Look at your `while` condition:

```
while ( (ans != "Y") || (ans != "y") || (ans != "N") || (ans != "n") )
```

In order to break out, *all* of those sub-conditions have to be false (so that the overall value is false).

The only way for the first condition to be true is if `ans` is "Y"... which means it definitely *won't* be equal to "y"...

In other words, your loop is equal to:

```
while (!(ans == "Y" && ans == "y" && ans == "N" && ans == "n"))
```

It would have to be a pretty special string to be equal to all four values.

You *actually* want:

```
while (ans != "Y" && ans != "y" && ans != "N" || ans != "n")
```

In other words, keep going while the value is not equal to *any* of the desired values. (An alternative would be to keep a set of "good answers"...

Comment: Okay I think I'm missing something. Doesn't the While loop read like this? Break out of the loop if and does not equal to "Y" or "y", etc. Meaning if it does equal to one of them, it should break?

Comment: @Omin: it's called a "while loop" for a reason. Repeat the loop **while** the condition is satisfied. Which in turn means, as soon as it's **not satisfied**, break the loop.

Comment: @Omin: No. It reads like this: "Break out if this condition is false: `ans` is not equal to "Y", or `ans` is not equals to "y", or `ans` is not equal to "N", or `ans` is not equal to "n". Think about how that condition can be false.

Answer (score 0):

```
        do {
            string ans = Console.ReadLine();
            if( ans == "Y" || ans == "y" )  {
                play = true;
                //break;
            }
            else if( ans == "N" || ans == "n" ) {
                play = false;
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write( "You have entered an invalid answer. Please choose from either Y or N: ");
                //ans = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } while ( (ans != "Y") && (ans != "y") && (ans != "N") && (ans != "n") );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
bool isValid = false;

        do
        {

            if( ans == "Y" || ans == "y" )  {
                play = true;
                isValid = true;
                //break;
            }
            else if( ans == "N" || ans == "n" ) {
                play = false;
                isValid = true;
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write( "You have entered an invalid answer. Please choose from either Y or N: ");
                ans = Console.ReadLine();
                isValid = false;
            }
        }while(isValid == false);
```

Relevant fiddle:https://dotnetfiddle.net/bxHY27